# Visual studio SP1 iso rather then web installer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have a number of dev computers in my department. Rather than have all of them download the SP1 data individually I would like to download one ISO and use it on each machine. 
We do not have the fastest internet connection and need to conserve bandwith for other users if possible.

Where would the ISO be located? Is there a different one for x86 -vs- x64?

Thanks
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have those files available to download on my MSDN subscription.
If you have an MSDN subscription login to and go to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/securedownloads/default.aspx

Comment: When I go to the MSDN downloads I only see the web installer stub not the ISO.  Odd. Thanks will have to take a look again.

Comment: I don't know, maybe there are differences in subscriptions but i have this: Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (x86, x64 WoW) - DVD (English) 
8/10/2008 View View Download
831 (MB)

Comment: And this Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (x86) - DVD (Multiple Languages)
3/8/2011 View View Download
1,519 (MB)

Answer (score 8):

The .iso is available [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210710), linked from the web installer [download page.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5)

(I suspect this should be a SuperUser question, though.)

Comment: Yea I saw that link but it is a straight file download rather than using MS file transfer utility. With our flakey connection and the size of the file having download resume is very helpful.  Thanks though.

Comment: You should probably specify that in the question, then!

Comment: That link doesn't specify or address the x86 -vs- x64 versions either.

Comment: There aren't separate versions for x86 and x64.  VS is a 32-bit application, regardless of which platform you develop on/for.